# Apply PCA for data stored in list

Tags: r, list, pca, prcomp

My image data is stored in a list. For every pixel (626257) of my image I have a vector containing all the values corresponding to the different wavelengths (44 wavelengths). Now I would like to carry out a principal component analysis (PCA). Unfortunately, I am not able to convert my listed data into the desired form. Here is the code to generate a dummy data set.

```
test = replicate(626257, rnorm(44, 3, 1),simplify = FALSE)
```

When I now try to carry out the PCA then the following error message pops up.

```
pca = prcomp(test, scale = F)
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

How can I convert my list into a suitable datatype?

Comment: If this is the format of your dataset, couldn't you simply use `as.data.frame` or `data.table::as.data.table`, and use `prcomp` from this point?

Comment: When I apply:  **test = as.data.frame(test)**, then the structure of my data changes. **View(test)** results in 10 columns with 44 entities, respectively. But I would expect 626257 columns with each 44 entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could change the `simplify = TRUE` in `replicate` and it should work

```
test <- replicate(10, rnorm(44, 3, 1),simplify = FALSE)
pca = prcomp(test, scale = FALSE)
```